# css не хочет обновляться дизайн

Tags: css

После замены изображения фона, и замены адреса на изображение с `backgblock.JPG` на `backgblock.png` в css файле, вместо нового изображения ничего нету. При просмотре кода элемента остается старый адрес `backgblock.JPG`. Все будет корректно отображаться только в том случае, если очистить кэш сайта. Но все пользователи не готовы это сделать, есть решение?

Comment: Посмотрите решение тут  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710497/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-style-c/710509#710509

Comment: можно в ссылке GET переменную cо случайным числом.